# Incorrect string value: '\xE2\x80\xAF(fo...' for column 'description' at row 1 Error: INSERT INTO my_table_name

Tags: mysql, character-encoding

Sometimes, when the text is copy pasted from a third website in my **form based application (in the textarea) the data don't get inserted in database**, instead throw this below error.

> Incorrect string value: '\xE2\x80\xAF(fo...' for column 'my_column_name' at row 1 Error: INSERT INTO my_table_name

I tried the below query in mysql workbench to solve this issue.

```
ALTER TABLE my_database_name.my_table CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8
```

But I am getting the below error from the database.

> Error Code: 1118. Row size too large. The maximum row size for the used table type, not counting BLOBs, is 65535. This includes storage overhead, check the manual. You have to change some columns to TEXT or BLOBs

Answer (score 0):

Your column data type accepts maximum limit of 65535 bytes. you need to change the column data type to `text` or `BLOB`

One more thing while copying content from website or word document just paste in any plain text editor and check whether expected content is copied

You can use `$content= preg_replace('/[\xE2\x80\xAF]/', '', $content);` in programming. the above example is in PHP

Comment: `text` or `CLOB`.

Comment: text would be fine

Answer (score 0):

Don't use whitespace in names:  hex `E280AF` is UTF-8 FOR "NARROW NO-BREAK SPACE".

I worry that doing `ALTER TABLE my_database_name.my_table CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8` without first diagnosing the problem has only made things worse.

You were probably using latin1 before?  Did you have any other non-English text in the database?  They may (or may not) be messed up.

We may be able to fix the mess, but we need to know more details about what you originally had, and what steps lead to this.

Also, what language(s) do you expect your customers to be using?

Comment: Nowhere I used white-spaces in name. Yes I used latin1 before. I do not have any non-English text in database. In short, my users fill-up this form which inserts data into the database on submission. Normally it works smoothly(regardless of whether the text is copied from a third website or not) but sometimes the error mentioned in the question occurs failing the insertion. Even copying the text to a text editor(i.e notepad++) as an intermediate step does not help. The only thing works then is typing that text manually and submitting the form.